# How to select multi-line strings (including spaces), return true if found - PowerShell/SQL Batch

Tags: sql-server, powershell, batch-file, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have used select-string to validate strings found on one line, however I need PowerShell to recognise multi-line strings, as well as meeting all three conditions (see below)

Output within .log file that needs to be selected:

```
Return Value
------------
           0
```

I would want something to validate the following string values (all three to be met to return true)

```
"Return Value", "------------", "           0"
```

I have tried this, however this is the equivalent of OR not AND in a filter

```
| Select-String -pattern "Return Value", "------------", "           0"
```

Sources: http://ss64.com/ps/select-string.html
       : http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1253397-1351-1.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **regex** with the multiline option:

```powershell
$a = 
@'
Return Value
------------
0
'@

$b = 
@'
Return Value
------------
1
'@

[regex]::Match($a, 'Return Value\s*------------\s*0', [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Multiline).Success # true
[regex]::Match($b, 'Return Value\s*------------\s*0', [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Multiline).Success # false
```

If you post an exmpale of your log, I can adapt the script more to your needs.

Comment: I have managed to incorporate your code into my .bat file logic and it is working perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Please close the answer (mark it as solved using the green check Image)